# How to get selected value from rich text area in java script

Tags: javascript

I am using jqte rich text editor , i want to get selected value only using java script

This kind of functionality work in normal text area for me but not work with rich text area

code for html text Area

```
$scope.ShowSelection = function ()
      {
        var selectedWordArr = [];  
        var textComponent = document.getElementById('txtEditor');
        var selectedText;
        // IE version
        if (document.selection != undefined)
        {
          textComponent.focus();
          var sel = document.selection.createRange();
          selectedText = sel.text;
        }
        // Mozilla version
        else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined)
        {
          var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
          var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
          selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
          selectedWordArr[0] = startPos;
          selectedWordArr[1] = selectedText;
           console.log("selectedWordArr",selectedWordArr);
          return selectedWordArr;
        }
      }
```

but i want same functionality for rich text area

Comment: It's not really a textarea, it's a content editable div, so most methods that work on textareas will not work on it. You have to read the documentation to figure out how to get the value.

Comment: by using window.selection i am able to capture selected text from content editable div